Is there an established mapping from longitude-latitude to the face of a icosahedron?
Given a longitude and latitude, I’d like to map that to the face of an isocahedron projected onto the sphere (earth). The orientation of the isocahedron doesn’t matter so if there is a convenient or common way to set that up like putting faces along the equator or prime meridian that’s fine. I’m thinking the best way to do this is convert to spherical coordinates and then find the three closest vertices. I’m hoping there’s a library or general mapping to polyhedrons I just haven’t been able to dig up.
